# params.require(:article).permit(:name, :story) not mapping to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails and I am working on a blog. I'm facing the problem that one of the fields of the form is not mapping to the database. When I save a new article the name maps to the db but not story. I end Up having a null column in the db.

**My migration**

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :story

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**forms/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :story %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :story %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new 
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:name, :story)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show your `log/development.log` with `create` action.

Answer (score 1):

Uses debugger gem and check the params are passes correct it will be good if you can just share the  devlopment.log